# Create Istio ingressgateway successful, but cann't find the gateway

Tags: istio, seldon-core

I create a private k8s cluster, 1.24.8

then I install istio 1.17.2 by these commands:

```bash
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -
cd istio-1.17.2
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
istioctl install --set profile=demo -y
```

here is istio install result:
[image: istio install result]

then I want to create a ingressgateway, here is config yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: seldon-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
      targetPort: 80
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

apply result:

[image: result]

as you can see, I can't find the gateway in any namespaces.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

because there is same prefix gateways crd.
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit? how does it help? How to fix this issue? I faced the same issue.

Comment: use `kubectl get gw -A` to query instead of `kubectl get gateway -A`. because `gateways.gateway.networking.k8s.io` is the first obj to query `gateway`. `gw` is the alias name for `gateways.networking.istio.io`, only to this.